# When is shadowRoot available to a polymer component?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm having trouble understanding when access to the shadowRoot of a component is available. Here is an image of a set of nested components:

[image]

So there are a handful of components:

1. MortgageDetails: Component binding together a group of 3 other components
2. MoneyInput - Input component with *Amount* label
3. NumWithUnitsInput - Input component with *Term* label
4. RateInput - Input component with *Rate* label
5. PaymentSchedule: Component with corresponding label
6. DateInput: Component with *Start Date* label

I've instrumented the created and attached methods with log message printing the shadowRoot ( *sr => ...*) and I get the following:

```
mortgageDetails [FINE]: MortgageDetails created sr => null (:1)
moneyInput [FINE]:  MoneyInput created sr => null (:1)
numWithUnitsInput [FINE]:   NumWithUnitsInput created sr => null (:1)
rateInput [FINE]:   RateInput created sr => null (:1)
paymentSchedule [FINE]: PaymentSchedule created sr => null (:1)
dateInput [FINE]:   DateInput created sr => null (:1)
mortgageDetails [FINE]: MortgageDetails attached with sr => Instance of 'ShadowRoot' (:1)
```

The logging makes sense. Components are created in a reasonable order and then the attaching starts. The problem is though, the mortgage details is attached before its contained moneyInput is attached. If I add one more log statement in the *MortgageDetails.attached* I can see that its contained MoneyInput object has a shadowRoot:

```
mortgageDetails [FINE]: Composed moneyInput sr => Instance of 'ShadowRoot' (:1)
```

This is a problem for the way I'm doing things. I need some initialization event in the MoneyInput component to reach into the shadowRoot and attach some handlers. I can't use *created* because shadowRoot is not even set yet. I'm trying to use *attached*. I have code like this currently in the *attach* of MoneyInput:

```
  _amountElement = shadowRoot.querySelector('#money-amount')
    ..onBlur.listen((evt) => reformatAmount())
    ..onFocus.listen((evt) => reformatAmount())
    ..onKeyUp.listen((evt) { if(evt.which == 13) reformatAmount(); });
```

Since MortgageDetails is being attached and MoneyInput has not yet been attached, an instance of MortgageDetails can not use the contained MoneyInput as it would like as it is not fully initialized. For example, in MortgageDetails *activate* I have:

```
(mortgageAmountInput = $["mortgage-amount"] as MoneyInput)
  ..label = r" $ Amount of Loan"
  ..onBlur.listen((_) => recalc())
  ..onFocus.listen((_) => recalc());
```

This fails because MoneyInput's *activate* has not been called. I think what I really need is an event that says the shadowRoot has been set, then on that event I could do my initialization.

What am I missing on the lifecycle of polymer elements?

Comment: What event handlers are you adding? Can you use declarative events in the template instead? I think if you could post some of your templates it would be easy to understand your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, if you're extending `PolymerElement` the order of the main callbacks will be `ready`, `created`, `attached`. These happen top-down: they're called on ancestors before descendants. It might confusing that `ready` is called first, but it's because `PolymerElement.created` calls it after setting up the DOM and even handlers, and because of constructor ordering that happens before your classes `created` constructor.

Polymer also adds a `domReady` method that you can override which is called when your element's children are guaranteed to have been created. That might be what you need.

See http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods for details on the lifecycle methods.

First I would see if you can sidestep the ordering issue with data-binding and declarative events, though.

Comment: Answer quite helpful - but does not match my _polymer-0.11.0+4_ observations. After adding logs for _ready_ and _domReady_ have found that using _ready_ satisfies my need. The observed order is actually _created_, _ready_, _attached_, then _domReady_. Specifically, by observation/induction, _ready_ should only be called when (1) shadowRoot has been set and (2) all descendents (or children) have had _ready_ called.

Regarding, preferring data-binding and declarative events, will study those capabilities more. I'm currently more comfortable with code than markup which goes against the grain.

Comment: Are you extending `PolymerElement` or using the `Polymer` mixin? The order of `created` and `ready` change based on that. If you use the base class, then `ready` is called from `prepareElement` which is called from the super constructor, so `ready` is called before your `created` constructor body. If you use the mixing, then your `created` is called first, which in turn must call `prepareElement`, which then called `ready`, so the order goes `created` then `ready`.

Comment: I define like: _class MortgageDetails extends PolymerElement_. For each of _created_ (a named ctor), _ready_, _attached_, and _domReady_ I first call super method and then log the message, then do any work. The order I see messages is _created_, _ready_, _attached_, _domReady_. Is this advisable? Which is preferred, extending PolymerElement or using the mixin?

Answer (score 1):

I find your description difficult to understand but usually in `attached` after the `super.attached();` call all things are proper initialized.

If you can provide the minimal code that allows to reproduce your problem it would be easier to make concrete suggestions.

In core-elements (JavaScripts) `ready()` callback is used most of the time instead of `attached`. I haven't investigated which one is called earlier/later because `attached` (was `enteredView`) never failed me.

Comment: I'll try to improve the description. With or without super.attached() the containing polymer object attached is being called without its contained object's attached having been called yet. Maybe this is by design - I don't know. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong. This only became an issue with polymer 0.11.0. The point of the logs was to show that MortgageDetail (container) attached called but the contained instance MoneyInput's attached has not been called yet. I can clean it up and check into github as well.