# No shadow root in polymer element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In the created() method of my polymer element the this.shadowRoot is empty! This was not the case in the version 0.9.5+2. But now, in version 0.11.0+5 I get an error.
[image]

What did change? And what should I do? Where should I place the initialization of the shadow dom?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom elements not detecting children when instantiated in template of another custom element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499713/custom-elements-not-detecting-children-when-instantiated-in-template-of-another)

Comment: also a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468984

Answer (score 0):

This never worked for me. I always do this in `attached()` after the `super.attached()` call.

@Justin Fagnani answered with a more detailed explanation on this question [When is shadowRoot available to a polymer component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468984)

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I put all initialization code to the attached() method. Also the things I formerly did under enteredView(), which seems not to be called any longer.

Comment: `enteredView` was replaced by `attached`